# My app is all of a sudden saying it cannot find my app.tsx module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, webpack, package.json

my app was running on `localhost:3000` just moments ago with no problem, now all of a sudden I am getting the error:

`Module not found: Can't resolve './App' in '/my/path/etc/...'`

This is happening in my **`index.js`** file

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
import TimeAgo from "javascript-time-ago";
import { FirebaseAppProvider } from "reactfire";
import en from "javascript-time-ago/locale/en";

TimeAgo.addDefaultLocale(en);

const firebaseConfig = {
  //MY FIREBASE CONFIG
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <FirebaseAppProvider firebaseConfig={firebaseConfig}>
      <App />
    </FirebaseAppProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))
// or send to an analytics endpoint.
reportWebVitals();
```

**My file structure looks like this:**

[image]

If I change the import in my index file from

`import App from "./App";`

to

`import App from "./App.tsx";`

It compiles however a different error comes up:

`InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'createElement' on 'Document': The tag name provided ('/static/media/App.2d194585.tsx') is not a valid name.`

EDIT 1 (Added ts config):

```
    {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "baseUrl": "./src"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

Comment: What are you using to serve your app? Is this using Create React App or another framework?

Comment: @RobertCorponoi thanks for replying! yepp create react app, running `npm start`

Comment: A couple more questions. One, have you ejected? Two, Have you changed your tsconfig recently? Make sure you have `"baseUrl": "./src"` set in your tsconfig.

Comment: @RobertCorponoi i dont think i have ejected as im unsure of what that is, is that a command e.g. `npm eject`? I have added the baseUrl into my tsconfig however it hasnt fixed it, sorry!

Comment: Yes, ejecting is a npm script and it gives you control over the `webpack.config.js` and other build tools. If you don't have a `webpack.config.js` then you probably haven't ejected. Can you post your `tsconfig.json` file to make sure that the configuration is valid.

Comment: I have a webpack.config however no webpack.config.js! I have adde my tsconfig now, thanks so much! @RobertCorponoi

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237031/discussion-between-robert-corponoi-and-squish).